# csvcut output contains multiple header rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm using csvcut to filter a CSV file with about 1.5 million rows down to a subset of the columns. I've just discovered that the resulting output CSV has two rows containing the column labels: one at the top of the file as expected and another about 750k rows in. It's the latter that I'm completely baffled by. Is this being produced due to operator error or something totally unexpected from csvcut?

I'm simply doing a call to csvcut of the form:

```
csvcut -c <column name 1> <column name 2> ... <column name N> input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

ah it turns out there's no issue with csvcut. the additional row header was introduced farther upstream in the processing pipeline.